# Creating a recursive funciton in php to determine interest of a loan over 10 years

Tags: php, function, recursion

I understand the basics of recursive functions, but I want to create a recursive function to determine the interest of a loan ($100 000) over 10 years. Problem is that I'm stuck and in the wrong direction.

Years = 10, amount = $100 000, interest rate = 8% a year
What I want to calculate is the amount after 10 years.

I would also like to show the amount he has after every year, but I don't think that's even possible.

Here's the code I have atm:

```
<?php
function loan( $year,$amount ) 
{   
    if ( $year == 0 ) 
    {
        return 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $year = $year - 1;
        return ($amount =.1,8) + loan($year, $amount);
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo loan(10,100000);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you try to do for ($amount =.1,8) ?

Comment: There is a simpler solution using recurrent relations - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: @PaulLo it's the interest added

Comment: Should the  be `return $amount *1.8 + loan($year, $amount);`

Comment: BTW 1.8 is 80% interest. A payday loan perchance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$year = $year - 1;
return ($amount =.1,8) + loan($year, $amount);
```

into

```
$year = $year - 1;
$amount = $amount * 1.8;
echo 'I now have $ ' . $amount;
return loan($year, $amount);
```

And change your `return 1` into `return $amount`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, only there's still a small mistake I think, because after 10 years I end up with more than 35 million :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start by renaming your function, it should be returning the interest, so call it this:

function interest($years, $amount)

and then think about how you can call this recursively to add up the interest each year over the number of years.

Comment: Thanks, that does make more sense!

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're forced to do it recursively (e.g. homework), I would rather do it iteratively

```
function loan($year, $amount, $rate) {
    while ($year--)
        $amount *= (1 + $rate);

    return $amount;
}
```

Comment: @x3ro As you can see from the code, the iterative version is much shorter. Usually, shorter code has less bugs. It is also easier for most people to grasp iterative algorithms than recursive ones. I thought, this is obvious as well as common sense.

Comment: In my experience, one shouldn't assume things to be common sense, and especially not to assume things are "obvious", because they usually aren't, especially when answering beginner questions. On your code being "much shorter": When applying the formatting of your code the OPs code, we end up with 5 lines (you) against 7 lines. I agree that people tend to be better at understanding iterative algorithms, but only because thats what most code is using today, all over the place :)